# Where did the US 'N' registration letter come from?

Tags: usa, aircraft-registration

Why is the first letter in US registration numbers 'N'? Other countries seem to use a letter significant to their country, for instance 'G' for **G**reat Britain, 'F' for **F**rance, 'D' for Germany (presumably for **D**eutschland), and 'JA' for **Ja**pan.

Does 'N' have any significance at all?

Answer (score 17):

The origins of this can be traced back to CINA (the Commission Internationale de Navigation Aerienne / the Convention for the Regulation of Air Navigation) established as part of the Paris Peace Conference immediately after WWI.

A part of this conference was the adoption of a system of international aircraft identification still in use today. The U.S. delegation was allocated "N".

A number of theories exist as to *why* "N" was chosen specifically, and there's [a great article about it](http://www.aahs-online.org/articles/N-number.php) over at the American Aviation Historical Society.

Theories range from, the largest number of states begin with the letter N; to the recognition of the development of wireless communications by the U.S. Navy that had been using "N" as the prefix to its station call-sign identifiers since 1909.

Comment: Joint-largest number of states. There are 8 M's and 8 N's.

Comment: And the ITU link is the one generally accepted as being the correct one. And the only one that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

I'm building this post expanding on Danny Beckett's information, give him credit :-)

---

#### Short answer:

Since 1919, aircraft registration is based on international prefixes allocated by ITU to radiotelegraphic stations rather than on a specific system. N prefix was allocated to US by ITU in 1919, along with KDA-KZZ and W. The choice for this system for aviation matters is materialized in the [Chicago Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation) since 1944, and previously in the [Paris Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Convention_of_1919) it extended.

The question boils down to: Why did ITU allocate N and W (plus KDA-KZZ) to the US? instead of U, US or USA? The answer is likely US was not so involved in these matters at the beginning and choices were limited when the interest came:

- CINA (which would become ICAO in 1947) and ITU, both at the origin of the prefix system, are also two of the many international peaceful initiatives by European governments to prevent recurrence of conflicts in the region.
- ITU membership was reserved to States. Telegraph in the US was considered a matter of private companies, so US Government participation to ITU was not significant in the early years.
- US will send an observer to ITU in 1875, 10 years after its creation, and US did agree in 1903 in Berlin that radiotelegraphy between ships and shore would be free to competition (read: Marconi stations would answer non-Marconi stations), but refused to ratify ITU radio regulations (RR) until 1949.

I guess founding members of ITU helped themselves with prefixes, and when the others came they had indeed fewer choices. Whole blocks (single letter prefix) have been allocated to actual or expecting-to-be empires: Germany (A, D), GB (B, G, M, and V for the overseas colonies), France (F), Italia (I), Japan (J), US (N, W), Russia (R).

In the end what was named the "call letters" had to be renamed the "call signs" with the addition of figures, like "2" for Guernsey or "9K" for Kuwait.

#### Historical milestones in international aviation vs international communication

- 1865: *International Telegraph Union* (ITU) created in Europe to handle [telegraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_telegraphy) matters.
- 1875: Saint Petersburg Telegraphic Convention.
- 1906: ITU [Berlin Radiotelegraphic Convention](http://search.itu.int/history/HistoryDigitalCollectionDocLibrary/4.37.57.en.100.pdf). First convention about radiotelegraph.
- 1912: ITU [London Radiotelegraphic Convention](http://search.itu.int/history/HistoryDigitalCollectionDocLibrary/5.19.61.en.100.pdf)
- 1913: The [International Bureau of the Telegraph Union](http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-nr2002024313/) in Berne releases a list of prefixes for radiocommunication. N and other blocks allocated to US. N has no specific meaning, it just happened to be available.
- 1913: US Department of Commerce makes the International Bureau list [applicable in the US](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DOC-338492A1.pdf), in particular to ships and coastal stations.
- 1913: First passenger-carrying airline
- 1919: [Paris Convention on ATC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Convention_of_1919), prepared by [CINA](https://www.icao.int/EURNAT/Pages/HISTORY/history_1910.aspx), deals with how allies, defeated, and other countries aircraft can be regulated, e.g. can they fly over another country? Part of this is the adoption of the national radio prefixes for aircraft registration and marking too. US did not ratify the convention.
- 1927: [Washington Radiotelegraphic Convention](http://search.itu.int/history/HistoryDigitalCollectionDocLibrary/4.39.43.en.100.pdf), the aircraft marking system based on ITU proposal is agreed (is today Annex 7 of the [Chicago Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation)).
- 1929: [Warsaw Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Convention) sets aviation-related liability laws prepared by Paris-based CITEJA, Comité International Technique des Experts Juridiques Aériens.
- 1932: ITU is renamed *International Telecommunication Union* (Madrid Convention)
- 1944: [Chicago Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation) extends Paris Convention and creates [PICAO](https://applications.icao.int/postalhistory/from_picao_to_icao_organizational_similarities.htm), a temporary organization to replace CINA
- 1947: ITU is now part of UN
- 1947: PICAO becomes [ICAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization), ICAO is part of UN.

#### Agreement on radiotelegraph practices and station callsigns

At the beginning of the 20th century, [radiotelegraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_telegraphy) ("wireless") was a new technology and communications with ships were handled using several variants of [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code), [Q-Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_code) and protocols, by commercial operators like [Marconi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marconi_Company), according to their own practices. Even uniqueness of radio station identifiers among all involved stations was not guaranteed.

Such a technology used worldwide required some international agreements on important matters like frequencies, techniques, codes, station identifiers, etc. These agreements were obtained through formal radiotelegraphic conventions, in particular:

- [Berlin Radiotelegraphic Convention](http://search.itu.int/history/HistoryDigitalCollectionDocLibrary/4.37.57.en.100.pdf) in 1906
- [London Radiotelegraphic Convention](http://search.itu.int/history/HistoryDigitalCollectionDocLibrary/5.19.61.en.100.pdf) in 1912

These conventions established standards to be implemented by involved stations, of which a standard use of station identifiers (the "call letters").

#### Agreement on country prefixes for callsigns

Station identifiers had still to be delivered by different States, an agreement had to be found to ensure they would be unique. In April 1913 the [International Bureau of the Telegraph Union](http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-nr2002024313/) released a list of national prefixes for station identifier allocation by States. This list was made official in the US by the Department of Commerce, in a document titled ["Radio Call Letters"](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DOC-338492A1.pdf), in May 1913:

> - The Service Regulations of the Berlin and London Radiotelegraphic Conventions provide that the call letters of stations in the
>   international system must each be formed of a group of three letters
>   which shall be distinguishable from one another.
> - The London International Radiotelegraphic Conference made a partial allotment of call letters among nations which signed the convention
>   and the International Bureau at Berne, with the consent of such
>   nations, has modified and added to this assignment of call letters by
>   circular of April 23, 1913.
> - The distribution of call letters among nations thus authorized is printed below for the guidance of operators of all stations, ship and
>   shore, of the United States.

Followed a list of international prefixes:

- Q was reserved to prevent confusion with Q-Code sequences. The conventions also standardized this code, reserving QAA-QNZ to aviation and QOA–QQZ to marine.
- Including KDA-KZZ, N, W for the US. N and W were possibly selected because they were the unassigned whole blocks at the time, while U, a natural choice, was already shared between France/Austria/Hungary/Bosnia-Herzegovina. Just a guess.

> [image]

US DoC then spit this allotment: N for Government stations, W for stations of the Pacific (and some for the US Army), and KDA-KZZ for stations of the Atlantic.

#### Commission Internationale de Navigation Aérienne

The [Commission Internationale de Navigation Aérienne](https://www.icao.int/EURNAT/Pages/HISTORY/history_1910.aspx) (CINA) has been the precursor of [ICAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization). Its role was to help build international air navigation services.

To handle aircraft, ATC needed to identify them, and aircraft had to be registered at the State level, so that they could be linked to some legal system. CINA proposed to use a process similar to the one for radio stations, and to reuse [the same ITU prefixes](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/378.html), with some minor adjustments (like adding a hyphen after the prefix) but also some changes, e.g. Germany was removed from the countries with a prefix:

> [image]
> <sup>[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=SUhgPgzxZT8C&pg=PA14)</sup>

This proposition was adopted at [Paris Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Convention_of_1919) in 1919. Paris Convention would later be extended by Chicago convention, and CINA replaced by ICAO, an organization of the UN. The prefixes would be updated in 1929 to the ones used today.

[International Telecommunication Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Telecommunication_Union) (ITU) still maintains the list of prefix blocks in [Appendix 42](https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-R/terrestrial/fmd/Pages/call_sign_series.aspx) of the [Radio Regulations](https://www.itu.int/pub/R-REG-RR-2016), and ITU is a full member of ICAO (without vote right).

---

More in *Annex 7 – Aircraft Nationality and Registration Marks (commented [here](https://applications.icao.int/postalhistory/annex_7_aircraft_nationality_and_registration_marks.htm)*)

Comment: "W for stations of the Pacific (and some for the US Army), and KDA-KZZ for stations of the Atlantic". Are you sure about that? Assuming that this also relates to radio/TV stations, it's "W" east of the Mississippi and "K" to the west. `WTHR` in Indiana and `KIFI` in Idaho, for example. _Could just be me applying apples to oranges..._

Comment: @FreeMan: If you look at [this DoC document](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DOC-338492A1.pdf): "3d: W [...] for ship and coast stations on the Pacific coast and on the Great Lakes.", however I found something interesting, a [list of stations](https://books.google.com/books?id=ew9LAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA10) at that time, which uses W for East as you said. So it seems there is an error in the DoC document.