# What is the historical reasons to start Belgians registrations with "OO-"?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-registration

For many countries, the registration number begins with a obvious letter (F for France, D for German (Deutschland I guess), C for Canada,...). For other, historical reasons have already been covered here (e.g. [Where did the US 'N' registration letter come from?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/)).

But for Belgium, I find it weird to begin with [OO](https://www.airliners.net/search?registrationActual=OO-SFG&display=detail). Is there an historical reason for that? if so, what is it?

Comment: `D` is for `Djermany`. Just say it aloud and suddenly it makes sense. ;-)

Comment: And G for UK-registered aircraft (for some reason), EI for Ireland (Eire), RA for Russia, JA for Japan, I for Italy, UR for the Ukraine, CU for Cuba, YU for Serbia (formerly Yugoslavia), LX for Luxembourg, Z for Zimbabwe...

Answer (score 2):

Since nearly all aircraft have radios, the simplest solution was to make aircraft tail numbers the same as their radio callsigns. Belgium was allocated radio callsigns with the prefixes ON through OT by the ITU, though for whatever reason, they use only prefix OO for aircraft.

Comment: Well, now the question becomes: why did they get such radio callsigns?

Comment: and what is this "whatever reason"?

Comment: @Zeus Good question, but I suspect not topical here since it's not specific to aviation.